# How can I retrieve a Ajax call response through code?

Tags: java, xml, http

I apologize if my question uses wrong terminology because I am not even sure what this kind of action is called.

On a webapp, when I perform a certain action it seems to request for some kind of ajax response for some information. When I do inspect element, on the networks tab I can see the xml data that the response returns. (see Image link) I don't have access to the source code of the web app.

How can i retrieve that information and parse it in Java? Is this possible?

http://tinypic.com/r/2itodon/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You DO have access to the source code. That request was made through jquery which means that somewhere in there a call through $.get, $.post, or $.ajax was made. Look through the  tags on the page and follow the `src` attributes to find the culprit.

The only way that call could be made would be through the browser which has to download the source code to do it. This means you can get it to through network requests.

Comment: even after I find the source code that makes the call. How do I retrieve that data using java?

Comment: the sourcecode that makes the call would have the url that it's requesting as well as any parameters needed for that call. You can issue another http request in java to simulate the browser making that request and get the data directly.

Comment: I am not sure where to find the src attributes in the js code, but when I look at the header tab of the response that I want, i see the Request URL. When I create a http request in java, can I just use that Request URL and it's associated parameters to return me the xml data? http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=hwlcol&s=8

Comment: Yes that works too as long as the URL doesn't change

Comment: @mrtofu if this helped you, you should accept the answer

Comment: @mrtofu no problem :)

Comment: I have another question, wondering if you can answer it. Please look at this for the details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546421/how-do-i-read-in-the-xml-for-from-java-http-request . I think because i am creating a ajax request there is problem with cross-site requests which prevents me from getting the xml data. Do you know anything about that and how to solve it?