# How do I read in the XML for from java http request?

Tags: java, xml, http

When I perform a certain action on a web app, it performs a ajax call or something along that line that returns some data in XML format. When I click On Inspect element in the browser and click on the networks tab, I can see the XML response data that was requested. see: [image]

I tried to perform a http request in java to retrieve this XML data. Here is the java code:

```
private StringBuffer sendGet() {

    final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "131";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String url = "https://same as the request header";

    try {
        //create the http connection
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",CONTENT_LENGTH);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Sending 'GET' request to URL " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code:" + responseCode);

        //read in the get reponse
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine.toString());
        }

        //close input stream
        in.close();

        System.out.println("response is: " + response);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

For the URL I am creating a http request, I am using the exact same request URL in the ajax calls header. see:[image]

When I perform the GET request, I received a response code of 200 which I assume the request was successful, but on my log it displays no XML even though I try to print it out. The log displayed this:

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL https:"blah blah blah"
Response Code:200
response is:
```

I should also note that when I try to go to the request URL directly on the browser it's just a blank white page.

When I use a request URL that contains a webpage, the http request returns all the html and js in the DOM. But the request URL I was trying to use which is just a blank page returns a blank response to me even though there are suspose to be some xml data. What am I doing wrong? Why is it that I cannot retrieve and display the XML? Do I need to parse the XML before it can be displayed?

Comment: I do not see any https call in the Networks tab. All the calls are being made to http end-point. Can you point to the exact URL which you are trying to connect to?

Comment: @Sourabh I don't exactly understand your question. Essentially I just try to use the request URL provided in the networks tab to make the HTTP request. The response tab contains the XML data that I want to retrieve, but it seems like I am retrieving blank even though the http request returns a 200 response code. Should I be using the request URL?

Comment: yeah that img doesn't work for me. I suspect the issue is you're sending the request using the wrong method, per discussion in your other question. POST and GET are not the same, and usually have different results.

Comment: @KevinB I reuploaded all the pics. I will try making the request using postman. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `DocumentBuilder`:-

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
```

For printing `XML` :-

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); //pretty printing
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
System.out.println("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());
```

Comment: is the bufferreader incapable of reading XML? Is that why It returned blank?

Comment: @mrtofu no i dont think so, just provided the solution if you want to play with the XML, parse or traverse it , using `DocumentBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by changing it to a POST request (same as what the browser did). I also included the form data associated with that request as shown in the pictures up there.

```
private StringBuffer sendPost() {

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String url = "https://example.com/snowbound/AjaxServlet";
    final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "131";
    final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    final String ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.8";

    try {
        //create http connection
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", CONTENT_LENGTH);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        //form data
        String content = "documentId=3896&action=getAnnotationModel&annotationLayer=1&pageCount=1&pageIndex=0";

        //write output stream and close output stream
        output.writeBytes(content);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        //read in the response data
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine.toString());
        }

        //close input stream
        input.close();

        //print out content
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("response code: " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("respone is: " + response);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```